# I want Change ul element when a is active?

Tags: html, css

hello i have problem  can any one help me I want to change ul position when i click on a link on it. on the mediaquery
I try a lot of things to do it! here the code html css

this is my html code of nav bar.

```
<nav>

    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </label>

    <a href="home.HTML"><img class="image-logo" src="./image/logo-.png" alt="logo" /></a>
    <ul id="ul">
        <li><a  href="#contact">  </a></li>
        <li><a  href="#join">  </a></li>
        <li><a  href="#Vision"> </a></li>
        <li><a  href="#service">  </a></li>
        <li><a  href="home.HTML">   </a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is my css in this section of page

```
@media(max-width: 880px) {
    .checkbtn {
        display: block;
    }

    ul {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: #fff;
        top: 80px;
        left: -100%;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all .5s;
    }

    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        margin: 50px 0;
        line-height: 30px;
    }

    nav ul li a {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    a:hover, {
        background: none;
        background: dodgerblue;
    }

    #ul a:active {
        left: 100px;
        background-color: #000000;
    }

    #check:checked~ul {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by " I want to change ul position when i click on a link"?

Comment: not sure if you know the difference between an `unique identifier` and a `class`. Long story short, how you do it right now isnt correct, since an ID should only be used once on a page.

Comment: You have multiple id="a", a id should be unique.

Comment: @grumy i know this is my error

Comment: You havent answered the first question.

Comment: sorry i want to change the position on the li to left: 0px; then the user click on the li link

Answer (score 0):

To change position dynamically u can use Javascript or jQuery.

```
document.getElementById("ul").style.left = "100px";
```

Or  Jquery

```
$("#ul").css({left:x,top:y});
```

there is mistake in your code you cant give same `id` for all `a` inside `li`

You can change style of li using
`li.active{ background:red; }`

```
<li class="active"><a  href="#contact">  </a></li>
```

Comment: i change it i forget this thing befor i edit my code ..  this is not working because i want to change the ul position not change li!! 
when i clicke the a the change happen in the ul position

Comment: what change do u want to happen in ul?

Comment: if u want position to be updated on click use javascript or jQuery for that

Comment: i want to change the position of ul i say that  the position to the left when i click on a li .

Comment: is there any other solution without the JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: THIS 
document.getElementById("ul").style.left = "100px";
not useful  because i want the change happen when i click on the li item. 
and i don't want to use JavaScript and jQuery

Comment: Actually dynamic changes cant be done using HTML and CSS alone,you can change by by setting a new position with new class .newPosition{left:10px!important;} , but inorder to add that on click u need javascript or jQuery

Comment: i guess you don't  got me .. change element position by the other element position it work!

Comment: Ya ur question is not that clear now also am not fully able to understand .. anyway can u let me now when u get ur answer. thank you